# Remove fonts from Docker Context installation

Tags: fonts, context

I am building a Docker image with conTeXt included so that I can generate PDFs from Google App Engine. I will only be using a couple of commercial OpenType fonts in the documents.

In an effort to keep the docker image (and build times) small, I'd like to remove the standard fonts that come with Context (79MB), leaving Computer Modern as a fallback.

Is this possible, and if so, what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Depends on how you are installing context? Are you using context standalone? If so, the `mtx-update.lua` script simply `rsync`s a bunch of files. You could filter out the fonts so that they are not downloaded in the rsync process.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya, I figured you'd be the first to answer! :-)

Comment: Oops, hit enter without thinking about it. 

I am using standalone, and already rsynced the files and COPYed them into the Dockerfile so that it doesn't have to redownload on every container build. Then I'm just calling `mtx-update.lua` manually, which I got from the end of `first-setup.sh`

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I wasn't sure if the fonts were required by context, or where to make changes.

Comment: If you need a fallback, I'd use Latin Modern. This is context's default, and it may act up if it can't find it. And remember to have the math fonts as well. Everything else should be optional.

Comment: The`--flags` option to `mtx-update` is passed on to `rsync`. So, you can use that to exclude font files (see `rsync` man page for details). As an example of passing options to rsync, see [this](https://github.com/adityam/context-pkgbuild/blob/master/PKGBUILD#L64).

Comment: I meant Latin Modern, not Computer Modern.

On the math front, @Thomas this project will not be using any math fonts. Are they still necessary to keep around?

Comment: Math: yes, it can crop up in unexpected places (e.g., symbols for itemizations), so I'd recommend keeping them.

Comment: Are there any news here?